# Powershell not starting inside Windows Servercore Docker image

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-for-windows

After starting a Windows docker container (base image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019) on a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter host i cannot start a powershell inside it.

If i create an image from a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

WORKDIR /
WORKDIR /config

ADD /config/run.ps1 /config/run.ps1

CMD ["powershell", "./run.ps1"]
```

And try to run with `docker run -d -it my-image-name` i can see the error code `3221225781` in event log.

If i run `docker run -it my-image-name powershell` i get the error `failed to resize tty, using default size` and then nothing happens.

If i run `docker run -it my-image-name cmd.exe` i can enter the container but running `powershell` inside does nothing (no error message or any output).

I tried disabling antivirus and installing VC++ redistributables on the host but no change.

The same image is working fine for other customers on Windows Server 2019 hosts (not datacenter).

Is there any solution or any additional way for me to try and debug the problem? Could the datacenter edition be a problem?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413443/trouble-debugging-error-with-exit-code-3221225781-missing-libraries-in-windows?force_isolation=true

Comment: Thank you! The thing is it works for other customers. I would prefer not to create a special image just for one time. Do you know any reason _why_ it wouldn't work for this server?

Comment: The library isn't installed.

Comment: Installing VC++ redistributables on the host made no difference

Comment: Are dlls in same location on working and non working?  Is anything different with installation?  Maybe a PATH?

Comment: isolation of hyper-v or processes? The host kernel version must be either equal to or higher than ltsc2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem: Kaspersky.

As stated in the question i tried deactivating it but that didn't make a difference. What worked was completely uninstalling Kaspersky..

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

#WORKDIR /
#WORKDIR /config
WORKDIR c:\config
ADD run.ps1 c:\config\run.ps1


ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-NoProfile", "-File", "run.ps1"]
```

If I understood docker correctly on windows, the paths should also be windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that run.ps1 is in your /config folder in your build context? If so, you're defining /config as your working directory.  If you want to copy the script into there just use the current directory.   is relative to your working directory if you use a relative path. All subsequent commands will use the working directory as your base path.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
WORKDIR /config
COPY /config/run.ps1 .

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "-File","run.ps1"]
CMD ["powershell"]
```