# Starting the MongoMemoryServer Instance failed error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs, mocha.js, supertest

I am trying to test an api using *mongodb-memory-server*, *mocha*, *chai* and *supertest*, Below is my code:

```
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require("mongodb-memory-server");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

(async () => {
    mongoServer = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    const mongoUri = mongoServer.getUri();

    await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
})();
```

This is the error I got:

```
Starting the MongoMemoryServer Instance failed, enable debug log for more information. Error:
 UnexpectedCloseError: Instance closed unexpectedly with code "3221225781" and signal "null"
Exit Code is large, commonly meaning that vc_redist is not installed, the latest vc_redist can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
    at MongoInstance.closeHandler (C:\Users\user\Documents\server\node_modules\mongodb-memory-server-core\lib\util\MongoInstance.js:290:58)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

I have tried using the latest version 8.x.x

Comment: Did you try installing vc_redist as mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Yes, I installed it

Comment: Here is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58440626/2282634